# How to dynamically create windows forms in a console application

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am working on my own programming language using Visual Basic 2010, Is there any way you can dynamically create windows forms in console application without any extra ad-on. If so.. Can you even keep it responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a console application you'll have to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms. Then the basics are:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim NewForm As New System.Windows.Forms.Form
    NewForm.Text = "New Form"
    'Add any other settings or controls you want
    NewForm.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

That will wait until the form is closed before exiting the application. Is that the kind of thing you had in mind?